# How to sort a list of lists with Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists:

```py
list_of_lists = [[42,34,9,-1,0],[-17,9,23,67,5],[101,78,9,100,-87]]
```

How do I sort it numerically so that each list is in ascending order?

Comment: Did you try using the `sorted` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method.

```py
for l in list_of_lists:
    l.sort()
```

`list_of_lists` now looks like:

```
[[-1, 0, 9, 34, 42], [-17, 5, 9, 23, 67], [-87, 9, 78, 100, 101]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect it was going to be that straightforward.

Comment: No problem, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read about the list functions [`sort` and `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html), as well as [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Finally:

```py
list_of_lists = [[42,34,9,-1,0], [-17,9,23,67,5], [101,78,9,100,-87]]
list_of_lists = [sorted(sublist) for sublist in list_of_lists]
#             = [[-1, 0, 9, 34, 42], [-17, 5, 9, 23, 67], [-87, 9, 78, 100, 101]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort list of lists like given below:

```py
new_list = []
for li in list_of_lists:
    new_list.append(sorted(li))
list_of_lists = new_list
```

> [[-1, 0, 9, 34, 42], [-17, 5, 9, 23, 67], [-87, 9, 78, 100,
> 101]]